# Add legend color in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to vba programming so bear with me.

I am trying to make the line and markers red for these two plots in my graph but my script only colors the first one. How do I use with selection (or something different) in a loop?

```
With ActiveChart
l = 1
    Do Until l = 3
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(l).Name = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & 8 + l)
        .SeriesCollection(l).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("B7:F7")
        .SeriesCollection(l).Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & 19 + l + LotAmount & ":F" & 19 + l + LotAmount)
        With Selection
        .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
        l = l + 1
    Loop
End With
```

This is probably piece of cake, so I am hoping it's an easy solve for you Guys :)

Best Regards

Lonnie

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ambiguous. You want to loop through several charts but start with

```
with activechart
```

So your series name, values and color are only applied to the `ActiveChart`. By the way, you use `With selection` but you didn't really `.Select` anything before. Here is some code you could change a bit:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sht as worksheet
Dim cht as ChartObject

Set sht = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Your sheet name") ' Sheet "Data"?
For Each cht in sht.chartObjects
    If cht.name = "Chart4" or cht.name = "Chart5" or cht.name = "Chart6" Then
        With cht.chart.SeriesCollection[(l)]
            .NewSeries
            .Name = sht.range("A" & 8 [+ l])
            .XValues = sht.Range("B7:F7")
            .Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & 19 [+ l + LotAmount] & ":F" & 19 [+ l + LotAmount])
        End With
        With cht.chart.ChartArea
            .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Didn't try it but you can use this as a start. Don't hesitate for any queries. Hope this helps!

PS: Always use Option Explicit (makes variable declarations mandatory)
Edit: Only last three charts

Comment: Thanks for you answer, what you write makes a lot of sense. I Have a question to the above code. I have 6 active Graphs on my sheet and only need to apply this to the last three (Chart4, Chart5 and Chart6). As I read you code it will change all the charts?

Comment: @JiheL you could use `Select Case cht.name` , and then use `Case "Chart4", "Chart5", "Chart6"`

Comment: @ShaiRado Yeah you're right but it wouldn't be the proper way here as we will have 3 times the same code in each `case`